# Functionality to check the date in ACF with the real date and output different function values

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

Maybe you can help me.
I need to improve this functionality to check the date in ACF with the real date and output different function values. When event date end return "END" or "0". Else return "cont" or "1"

Unfortunately, it absolutely does not want to check the dates)

```
function add_calendar() {  
$cur_date = date("Ymd\THis\Z", time());
$starttime =  date('Ymd\THis\Z', strtotime(get_field('start')));  
$endtime = date('Ymd\THis\Z', strtotime(get_field('end')));  
$title = get_the_title();
if($cur_date <= $endtime){
$string = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&dates=" . $starttime . "%2F" . $endtime . "&details=&location=&text=" . $title;
return $string;
} else {
    return "#";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but you might try using PHP's `DateTime()` class. It's more reliable and I believe it supports date comparisons in the way you're using:

```
function add_calendar() {  
    $cur_date = new \DateTime();
    $starttime = new \DateTime(get_field( 'start' ));  
    $endtime = new \DateTime(get_field( 'end' ));  
    $title = get_the_title();
    if ( $cur_date <= $endtime ) {
        $string = 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&dates=' . $starttime->format( 'Ymd\THis\Z' ) . '%2F' . $endtime->format( 'Ymd\THis\Z' ) . '&details=&location=&text=' . $title;
        return $string;
    } else {
        return '#';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you know how to save returned value to ACF custom fields?)

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
function add_calendar() {
$cur_date = date("Y-m-d", time());
$starttime =  date('Ymd\THis\Z', strtotime(get_field('start')));
$endtime = date('Ymd\THis\Z', strtotime(get_field('end')));
$close_event = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(get_field('end')));
$title = get_the_title();
if($cur_date <= $close_event){
$string = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&dates=" . $starttime . "%2F" . $endtime . "&details=&location=&text=" . $title;
return $string;
} else {
    return "#";
}
}
```